# htaccess rewrite for a rewritten URL that is already indexed by Google

Tags: .htaccess, seo

Example:

1) URL (a poorly constructed one) is already indexed by Google:
www.abc.com/index.php?product=zzz

2) The URL is rewritten by using the following rewrite rule:
RewriteRule ^zzz$ index.php?product=zzz [L,NC]

The above is working fine, but we want to tell Google that the page has permanently moved from the URL in (1) URL www.abc.com/index.php?product=zzz to the URL in (2) www.abc.com/zzz

3) So now we apply the following rule above the rule (2):
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^product=zzz [NC]
RewriteRule index http://www.abc.com/zzz? [L,R=301]

This results in an infinite loop.  How do we tell Google that our site has changed from www.abc.com/index.php?product=zzz to www.abc.com/zzz?  Or will Google do this by themselves?

-----Current full htaccess rules resulting in infinite loop:-----

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^product=zzz [NC]
RewriteRule index http://www.abc.com/zzz? [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^zzz$ index.php?product=zzz [L,NC]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your existing rules with this code:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+index\.php\?product=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(zzz)/?$ /index.php?product=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Your solution worked perfectly!  Do you care to explain what is involved, and what is different from the rules I was using?

Comment: Main difference is use of `THE_REQUEST` which represents original HTTP request as received by Apache and doesn't get overwritten by various RewriteRule statements. Your rule was acting on string index which is also matching on rewritten URI `index.php?product=zzz` hence those rules are going into infinite loop.